# Python Anaconda Proxy Setup via .condarc file on Windows

Tags: python, proxy, anaconda, conda

I am having trouble going through a proxy for Anaconda install conda on a Windows 7 machine. How do I use a proxy?

http://conda.pydata.org/docs/config.html

[the above link is broken, use this one instead](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/configuration.html)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I had to create a .condarc file at the `C:\Users\username` folder.

Use `copy con .condarc` file if it does not exist at folder above.

File content is:

```
proxy_servers:
    http: http://username:password@corp.com:8080
    https: https://username:password@corp.com:8080
```

Two notes:

- Do not use tabs, there must be space between `http:` and `http://...`
- You might not have a username and password for the proxy. Leave out the `username:password` part and it will still work

Comment: Hello, I use the username:password in order to authenticate via commandline but it still gives me this error `Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))`

Comment: 'http://' and 'https://' parts could be dropped in addition to username and password parts if the proxy address is an IP address.

Comment: I get this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67297278/valueerror-check-hostname-requires-server-hostname

Answer (score 7):

On Windows 10 you need to set up additionally the domain name in the .condarc:

```
channels:
  - admin

show_channel_urls: true
allow_other_channels: true

proxy_servers:
  http: http://domainname\username:password@proxyserver:port
  https: http://domainname\username:password@proxyserver:port

ssl_verify: true
```

Comment: how do you write the username and pass word? is it to be typed inside quotes? also shall the username be for example 'abc.def@mail.com'? also what is password has an @ , how to do this? Thanks. :)

Comment: you have to url_encode your password so that you can put in the url format.

Comment: You can remove the channels part and set ssl_verify: false and it'll work. for me channels section was causing issue so I removed it.

Comment: Yes, right @HSRathore Thanks for the solution, it's working after removing channel part.

Answer (score 0):

On windows 10 machine also. Following accepted answer's format gives a load error, invalid YAML.

Changing '//' to '\' fixed the issue for me.

```
proxy_servers:
  http: http:\username:password@corp.com:8080
  https: https:\username:password@corp.com:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case on a linux machine behind a McAfee web-gateway proxy, only the following setup worked for conda (I removed the http proxy):
hostname:~ # cat .condarc
proxy_servers:
  https: https://domain\user:password@server:port

hostname# conda install tensorflow
Solving environment: done

### Package Plan

environment location: /anaconda3

added / updated specs:
    - tensorflow

The following packages will be downloaded:

```
package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
markdown-3.0.1             |           py36_0         107 KB
gast-0.2.0                 |           py36_0          15 KB
libprotobuf-3.6.0          |       hdbcaa40_0         4.1 MB
protobuf-3.6.0             |   py36hf484d3e_0         610 KB
conda-4.5.12               |           py36_0         1.0 MB
termcolor-1.1.0            |           py36_1           7 KB
tensorflow-base-1.9.0      |mkl_py36h2ca6a6a_0        75.7 MB
grpcio-1.12.1              |   py36hdbcaa40_0         1.7 MB
astor-0.7.1                |           py36_0          43 KB
tensorboard-1.9.0          |   py36hf484d3e_0         3.3 MB
tensorflow-1.9.0           |mkl_py36h6d6ce78_1           3 KB
absl-py-0.6.1              |           py36_0         152 KB
_tflow_190_select-0.0.3    |              mkl           2 KB
------------------------------------------------------------
                                       Total:        86.7 MB
```

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

```
_tflow_190_select: 0.0.3-mkl
absl-py:           0.6.1-py36_0
astor:             0.7.1-py36_0
gast:              0.2.0-py36_0
grpcio:            1.12.1-py36hdbcaa40_0
libprotobuf:       3.6.0-hdbcaa40_0
markdown:          3.0.1-py36_0
protobuf:          3.6.0-py36hf484d3e_0
tensorboard:       1.9.0-py36hf484d3e_0
tensorflow:        1.9.0-mkl_py36h6d6ce78_1
tensorflow-base:   1.9.0-mkl_py36h2ca6a6a_0
termcolor:         1.1.0-py36_1
```

The following packages will be UPDATED:

```
conda:             4.5.4-py36_0             --> 4.5.12-py36_0
```

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Downloading and Extracting Packages
markdown-3.0.1       |  107 KB | ####################################### | 100%
gast-0.2.0           |   15 KB | ####################################### | 100%
libprotobuf-3.6.0    |  4.1 MB | ####################################### | 100%
protobuf-3.6.0       |  610 KB | ####################################### | 100%
conda-4.5.12         |  1.0 MB | ####################################### | 100%
termcolor-1.1.0      |    7 KB | ####################################### | 100%
tensorflow-base-1.9. | 75.7 MB | ####################################### | 100%
grpcio-1.12.1        |  1.7 MB | ####################################### | 100%
astor-0.7.1          |   43 KB | ####################################### | 100%
tensorboard-1.9.0    |  3.3 MB | ####################################### | 100%
tensorflow-1.9.0     |    3 KB | ####################################### | 100%
absl-py-0.6.1        |  152 KB | ####################################### | 100%
_tflow_190_select-0. |    2 KB | ####################################### | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done