# unable to update anything in conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have just installed the most recent Anaconda version (win 10 64bits) and I am now unable to update any package.
My `condarc` file contains my proxy settings. This used to work perfectly fine with the previous anaconda version.

```
proxy_servers:
  http: http://myproxy.com:8080
  https: https://myproxy.com:8080
```

But running `conda update conda` triggers an error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed
 urllib3.exceptions.ProxySchemeUnknown: Not supported proxy scheme None
```

What is the issue here? Arent my proxy setting written in the correct way?
Thanks!

Comment: how do you authenticate proxy?
Check if you are following this guideline
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883371/python-anaconda-proxy-setup-via-condarc-file-on-windows

Comment: yes...but I do not need any password/login.... I am puzzled here

Comment: What does `conda config --show proxy_servers` output? That will show whether it is parsing correctly (YAML is sometimes finicky about whitespace).

Comment: `proxy_servers:
  http: myproxy.com:8080
  https: myproxy.com:8080`