# Downloading a csv using http get request?

Tags: python, python-3.x

when i open this url `https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod/AAPL.US?from=2020-01-05&to=2020-02-10&period=d&fmt=csv&api_token=OeAFFmMliFG5orCUuwAKQ8l4WWFQ67YX` in browser , the browser automatically downloads the csv file containing the data.

is there a way to have that file downloaded using python request module ? or any other module ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the text content by `.text` then store the value in a csv file locally.

```py
import requests

data = requests.get('https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod/AAPL.US?from=2020-01-05&to=2020-02-10&period=d&fmt=csv&api_token=OeAFFmMliFG5orCUuwAKQ8l4WWFQ67YX').text

with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: it throws error : ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname

Comment: It worked fine on my computer check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67297278/valueerror-check-hostname-requires-server-hostname

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "downloaded", do you want to get the data inside your python script or want to store the downloaded csv on your storage.

A simple GET request is enough to get the data of the csv, you can try it using POSTMAN, or just try the following code in python

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod/AAPL.US?from=2020-01-05&to=2020-02-10&period=d&fmt=csv&api_token=OeAFFmMliFG5orCUuwAKQ8l4WWFQ67YX")
print(response.text)
```

If you do want to download and store, a simple solution would be to get the data using GET request and then write to a file, or format the data in the necessary format and then store.

Comment: yeah i want to download and store the csv to storage

Comment: @Sam Hi, you can follow Epsi95 's answer to store the data. The data you are receiving is already in the form of csv, meaning, the values are separated by commas, so his answer will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the raw csv file by making a **get** call using the requests module to the particular link.

After you've got the raw file, just put the contents to a new csv file. Specifically, you can do this.
This will result in a file being generated named "test.csv" and it will have all the contents of the file in the URL

```
import requests
import csv
link = "https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod/AAPL.US?from=2020-01-05&to=2020-02-10&period=d&fmt=csv&api_token=OeAFFmMliFG5orCUuwAKQ8l4WWFQ67YX"
csv = requests.get(link)
open("test.csv", "wb").write(csv.content)
```

Comment: tried that earlier but it throws error : ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname

Comment: Can you maybe provide me the code snippet?

Comment: that particular code is now overwritten by many other unsuccessful attempts but i ran the code you provided again to make sure i didnt miss any thing but its the same for this one , same error

Comment: This might be an isssue with urllib3. Can you try it again,  this time make sure you use a different version

pip install urllib3==1.25.11

then try running the same code again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to immediately have the data in a table form for analysis and then save it locally for future use:

```
import pandas as pd

url = r'https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod/AAPL.US?from=2020-01-05&to=2020-02-10&period=d&fmt=csv&api_token=OeAFFmMliFG5orCUuwAKQ8l4WWFQ67YX'

df = pd.read_csv(url)
df.to_csv('insert_file_name.csv')
```

Pandas is super useful for doing quick data analysis.