# `ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname` occurs when installing matplotlib using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, cmd, pip

Some erros returned when I tried to install matplotlib in cmd.
Version of pip is 21.2.3.
Version of python is 3.10.0
I also tried to install it in pycharm.But failed again.
I don't know how to solve this problem.

This is my command in cmd: `pip install matplotlib`

there is the output when I executed my command.

```
raise ValueError("check_hostname requires server_hostname")
ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname
```

Comment: Check this question and it's answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67297278/valueerror-check-hostname-requires-server-hostname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be some compatibility issues with python 3.10 and matplotlib right now. I found some similar issues [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69604071/8082993). Hopefully, they will be fixed with time. For the time you might try to create a python 3.8/3.9 environment and pip install a compatible matplotlib without much trouble. I usually prefer the [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) python distribution when working in windows since it comes with numpy, matplotlib, pandas etc. modules out of the box.