# cannot install the pytz library

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytz

So I want to create an app that gets the time by time zone. I have read that the pytz library is for Timezone and for getting date and time we use datetime library. but I cannot import the pytz library. internet said that it's not one of the standard python library so I downloaded it manually with this command :

```
pip install pytz
```

but it gives this error :

```
ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname
```

I think this error is something related to my internet.
I have searched for this error and found that it's because the proxy or VPN. but mine is off.
can you help me with this? appreciate it.

**EDIT**

I mean can you check if it installs correctly on your device or not? with the command I said above.

**EDIT FOR @MisterMiyagi**

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 173, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 203, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 315, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 94, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 472, in resolve       
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 341, in resolve       
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 151, in __bool__        
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 140, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 128, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 29, in _iter_built
    for version, func in infos:
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 272, in iter_index_candidate_infos
    result = self._finder.find_best_candidate(
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 851, in find_best_candidate
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 798, in find_all_candidates
    page_candidates = list(page_candidates_it)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\sources.py", line 134, in page_candidates    
    yield from self._candidates_from_page(self._link)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 758, in process_project_url
    html_page = self._link_collector.fetch_page(project_url)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 490, in fetch_page       
    return _get_html_page(location, session=self.session)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 400, in _get_html_page   
    resp = _get_html_response(url, session=session)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 115, in _get_html_response
    resp = session.get(
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\session.py", line 454, in request
    return super().request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\adapter.py", line 53, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen     
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connection.py", line 359, in connect
    conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connection.py", line 500, in _connect_tls_proxy
    return ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 453, in ssl_wrap_socket  
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 495, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 512, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1027, in _create
    raise ValueError("check_hostname requires server_hostname")
ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname
```

Comment: Can you please provide the complete error message, including the traceback?

Comment: yessir.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `pip install pytz` gives me the following output and installs fine using a python3 environment:

```
$ pip install pytz
Collecting pytz
  Downloading pytz-2022.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (503 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 503.5/503.5 KB 7.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pytz
Successfully installed pytz-2022.1
```

You could choose to download and install pytz in offline mode as a workaround ([inspired by this guide](https://gist.github.com/Quar/e63c733ce79b12992396a927b511ef70)):

1. Download the [.whl](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/2e/dec1cc18c51b8df33c7c4d0a321b084cf38e1733b98f9d15018880fb4970/pytz-2022.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl) file of [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) and put it into a directory named `requirements`.

```bash
mkdir requirements
cd requirements
wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/2e/dec1cc18c51b8df33c7c4d0a321b084cf38e1733b98f9d15018880fb4970/pytz-2022.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

2. Make a `requirements.txt` with the content `pytz`:

```bash
echo "pytz" > requirements.txt
```

3. Install the pytz package using pip:

```bash
pip install --no-deps --no-index --find-links=. -r requirements.txt
```

Other solutions might be found in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67297278/valueerror-check-hostname-requires-server-hostname/71060804#71060804). The most noteworthy solution probably being:

```bash
pip install pytz -i http://pypi.douban.com/simple --trusted-host pypi.douban.com
```

Please note that this makes pip use a HTTP connection instead of a HTTPS one. While PyPi doesn't support HTTP, [we can exploit douban's mirror which supports HTTP to circumvent this limitation](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10677).

Comment: ooo thats a long way. thank you very much. i'll try

Comment: It is in no way perfect. You should aim for a proper solution which provides a fix for any proxy shenanigans, though this is the best I could think as of right now.

Comment: hey i didn't get where is the requirements directory

Comment: You create it yourself. It's just a measurement to not accidentally overwrite your existing requirements.txt. I'll expand the answer to better explain this step.

Comment: sorry if i ask too much questions bc im new

Comment: @ParsaAd I did some digging, and found This: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71060804/19128226

If you haven't installed it manually already, could you please check whether that solution works?

Comment: but the cmd says "wget is not recognized"

Comment: No problem, I'm new to this community too.

Comment: i checked the link. good way. but there we have the source of the module "numpy" whats the source for pytz? like its "pypi.douban.com" in the link for numpy

Comment: It should be the same source. I'll update the answer with a command that worked for me.

Comment: success ! like i said , the problem was on my internet. i disabled proxy from settings and it installed. thank you for taking time on me.

Comment: No problem. I'm sad to see that I wasn't much of a help, but I'm glad you got it working. Have a nice day!