# How do I fix the error while creating an environment in conda

Tags: pycharm, anaconda

I have a new office laptop with anaconda and pycharm installed for the first time. While trying to create a new enviroment through the terminal in pycharm interface I get the below error

```
PS C:\Users\xxxx\PyProjects> conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3

PS C:\Users\xxxx\PyProjects>  conda create -n newenv37 python=3.7
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64'
```

what seems to be the issue? I can open the anaconda website on my laptop so doesnt look like its blocked. Any help is appreciated as I come from a non-tech background.

Comment: Hi, Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Nope unfortunately!

Comment: I found a solution. Let me post as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to set up your proxy servers in the .condarc configuration file first, see here

[Python Anaconda Proxy Setup via .condarc file on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883371/python-anaconda-proxy-setup-via-condarc-file-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I could fix it by disabling ssl.

Find .condarc file on your system. In windows it's located at c:/users/ and set ssl_verfiy: false

If the file is not present then just create a file with mentioned name. Content of the file would be:

ssl_verfiy: false
channels:
- defaults