# Anaconda Proxy Setup via .condarc fails

Tags: python, proxy, anaconda

I try to update Anaconda behind a corporate proxy. For this the network team gave me the parameters: proxy.subdomain.domain.de:1234. HTTP as well as HTTPS. However, everthing I try won't work. Either it doesn't show any effect or it returns a ConfigurationLoadError reasoned with "invalid yaml".

This configuration returns an error:

```
proxy_servers:
    http: http://proxy.subdomain.domain.de:1234
    https: https://proxy.subdomain.domain.de:1234
```

And this configuration doesn't work either:

```
proxy_servers: {http://proxy.subdomain.domain.de:1234, https://proxy.subdomain.domain.de:1234,}
```

I've already looked up a similar question, which solutions don't work for me, and the documentation:

[Python Anaconda Proxy Setup via .condarc file on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883371/python-anaconda-proxy-setup-via-condarc-file-on-windows)
https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/proxy/
https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/configuration.html

Can anyone please tell me what my mistake is and what the soulution is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer to it and it seems that is was mainly a matter of formatting:

```
proxy_servers:
  http: proxy.subdomain.domain.de:1234
  https: proxy.subdomain.domain.de:1234
```

I had too much spaces in front of the parameters, four spaces instead of only two spaces, and putting "http://" or "https://" in front of the parameter was also not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting the .condarc file as Artai stated worked for me too:

```
proxy_servers:
  http: proxy.company.edu:1234
  https: proxy.company.edu:1234
```